# Pandas reshape columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to reshape the pandas dataframe,

I have csv file that is in this format

```
#Result;ID;Date;Events;type
12;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item1
2;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item1
7.8;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item1
151;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item1
0;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item1
3;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item1
0;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item1
164;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item2
162;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item2
161;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item2
161;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item2
162;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item2
349;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item2
162;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item2
7.8;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item3
7.8;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item3
7.8;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item3
7.8;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item3
7.9;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item3
7.7;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item3
7.8;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item3
0;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item4
0;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item4
0;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item4
0;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item4
0;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item4
0.17;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item4
0;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item4
```

What I need is something like below (they are basically grouped by id, if even one of the events is 1 then it will be 1)

```
Item1;Item2;Item3;Item4;Events;Date;ID
12;164;7.8;0;1;10/01/2017 10:10;1240422
2;162;7.8;0;0;12/01/2017 09:15;1241468
7.8;161;7.8;0;0;12/01/2017 09:40;1241469
151;161;7.8;0;1;12/01/2017 10:00;1241470
0;162;7.9;0;0;12/01/2017 10:20;1241471
3;349;7.7;0.17;0;12/01/2017 10:40;1241472
0;162;7.8;0;0;12/01/2017 11:10;1241473
```

Any Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear, how the above dataframe is transformed to the below one, please give more clarity on how did those values of item1,item2..item4 in second csv file got them. And moreover show what you've tried.

Comment: In A we have column named #type that contain objects like item1, item2 etc. each needs to become new column.

item1 have id, you can use it to find item2 with the same id, same goes for item3 and item4 (some may have missing data and have no entries for them but thats is rare, 0 can be put there)

So group items by ID, the date will be the same for all the entries with same ID. As for the value for the itemX use the result from A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use dataframe reshaping:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csvtxt = StringIO("""Result;ID;Date;Events;type
12;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item1
2;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item1
7.8;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item1
151;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item1
0;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item1
3;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item1
0;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item1
164;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item2
162;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item2
161;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item2
161;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item2
162;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item2
349;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item2
162;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item2
7.8;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item3
7.8;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item3
7.8;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item3
7.8;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item3
7.9;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item3
7.7;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item3
7.8;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item3
0;1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;Item4
0;1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;Item4
0;1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;Item4
0;1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;Item4
0;1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;Item4
0.17;1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;Item4
0;1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;Item4""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvtxt, sep=';')
df_out = df.set_index(['ID','Date','Events','type'])['Result'].unstack().reset_index()
df_out.to_csv('out.csv', sep=';', index=False)
!type out.csv
```

Output in 'out.csv' file:

```
ID;Date;Events;Item1;Item2;Item3;Item4
1240422;10/01/2017 10:10;1;12.0;164.0;7.8;0.0
1241468;12/01/2017 09:15;0;2.0;162.0;7.8;0.0
1241469;12/01/2017 09:40;0;7.8;161.0;7.8;0.0
1241470;12/01/2017 10:00;1;151.0;161.0;7.8;0.0
1241471;12/01/2017 10:20;0;0.0;162.0;7.9;0.0
1241472;12/01/2017 10:40;0;3.0;349.0;7.7;0.17
1241473;12/01/2017 11:10;0;0.0;162.0;7.8;0.0
```

Comment: I have one more question, if the event value differs in one of the entries then it just creates duplicate like that: 1321446; 01.08.2017 11:45;0;11;155;0;
1321446; 01.08.2017 11:45;1;;;;7.8. The event value should be 1 if even one of them is 1 and 0 if all are 0.

Comment: Seems like there needs to be some grouping logic added.  Can you create a new question with sample data that has this situation and also, included the expected output.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.set_index('ID')\
  .join(df.pivot(index = 'ID', columns = 'type', values = 'Result'))\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop(columns  = 'type')
```

I'm quite confused where a lot of the values in the items columns come from, but I'm going to assume you just have a lot more data. This makes new columns for items, and sets the values to the ones in the Result column.